# Visualizing polynomial functions with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wish to create a tool where the plot updates instantly as the functions(statements) are typed in. I know about enter(), but that's for data and my data rarely changes (when zooming should occur, or when otherwise the plot would not fit in, if the curve is complicated), it seems to me that I have to manually loop over my newly typed statements I wish to plot, and clear the previous ones. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The example at http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stream.html might be helpful to take a look at.  I think you are going to want to run your data through the polynomial function and use that as the new data set for the graph.  The graph can then be seamlessly updated from one polynomial to another.

Comment: I don't get it, the example you linked uses different data for each new plot/graph/image, but the same functions. What I need is the opposite, my data is really simple, it's just a range(), but the functions are constantly changing.

Comment: You can't graph just a function though, you can only graph f(x) and since your function is changing, the data being graphed is also changing (otherwise every graph would look the same).  In your case, x is the same (your range) but what you want to graph is f(x) which becomes the data for the new plot.

Comment: you are right, as I am well aware of this. I've already wrote this, but as I said in the question, I did this with for loops and manually managing the functions. I was hoping, that with d3.js maybe there are nicer ways to accomplish the same thing.